# Trigger a cloud build pipeline using Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to create a cloud function listening to cloudbuilds topic and making an API call to trigger the build. I think I'm missing something in my index.js file (I'm new to Node.js). Can you provide a sample example of a Cloud Function making an API call to the Cloud Build API?

Here is my function:

```html
const request = require('request')

const accessToken = '$(gcloud config config-helper --format='value(credential.access_token)')';

request({
  url: 'https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/builds',
  auth: {
    'bearer': accessToken
  },
  method: 'POST',
  json: {"steps": [{"name":"gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil", "args": ['cp','gs://adolfo-test-cloudbuilds/cloudbuild.yaml', 'gs://adolfo-test_cloudbuild/cloudbuild.yaml']}]},
}, 
module.exports.build = (err, res) => {
  console.log(res.body);
});
```

I was executing the command `gcloud config config-helper --format='value(credential.access_token)'`, copying the token, and putting it as a value to the variable accessToken. But this didn't work for me.

Here is the error: `{ error: { code: 403, message: 'The caller does not have permission', status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED' } }`

Comment: Python doesn't run on node.js.  JavaScript runs on node.js.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I not developing the function in python but Javascript.

Comment: My function is deployed successfully now. But, I can't send the request because of PERMISSION_DENIED error. Do you know how to connect to the api using request model?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete, minimal code and the exact error message you see in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem and I have solved it by writing a small package, you can use it or read the source code.
https://github.com/MatteoGioioso/google-cloud-build-trigger
With this package you can **run a pre-configured trigger** from cloud build.
You can also extend to call other `cloud build` API endpoints.

As my understanding `cloud build` API requires either OAuth2 or a service account. Make sure you gave the right permission to `cloud build` in the gcp console under `IAM`. After that you should be able to download the `service-account.json` file.

Comment: what are the permissions that needs to be included in the service account ? I am getting permission denied error @madeo

Comment: @ArunRamachandran Hey, I am not really sure I remember, it has been 2 years since I did not touch it, but in my repository I have found this script

`#!/usr/bin/env bash
PROJECT=my-project

NUM=$(gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} --format='value(projectNumber)')

gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
${PROJECT}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
--member=serviceAccount:${NUM}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser \
--project=${PROJECT}`

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. Will check this out and update here :)

Comment: @ArunRamachandran let me know if it works, I will add it in the answer, thanks